# " Uncaught (in promise) " when calling the reject function inside a fetch 'then' method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is the code in question:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const opts = {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  };

  fetch(`/_api/myAPI`, opts)
  .then((res) => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      reject(res);
    } else {
      ...
```

If the url throws an exception a 401, when the execution reaches `reject(res);` it throws `Uncaught (in promise)`

Even after I add a `.catch` after the `.then` call, i.e.

```
  fetch(`/_api/myAPI`, opts)
  .then((res) => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      reject(res);
    } else {
      ...
   })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
   }
```

it still happens.

Why `reject` will throw this exception and how can I fix it?  My experience is limited to  `jQuery.Promise` and I don't a `reject` within a failure handler will trigger this error.

Comment: Wrapping fetch promise into a new promise is [an antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). And it causes ill effects here.

Comment: @estus Thanks for the informative comment!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you're rejecting the promise, you're immediately rejecting the promise that is wrapping that entire operation, so you would never get to that catch block.

An analogy: reject and resolve are to promises as return is to functions.

I think what you are trying to do is the code below.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const opts = {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  };
  fetch(`/_api/myAPI`, opts)
  .then((res) => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      return Promise.reject()
    } else {
      ...
      resolve(...);
   })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    reject();
   }
}
```

Comment: I know this thread is stale but is it possible that, at least in Chrome, it *always* displays that error when rejecting a promise? I think that's what I'm seeing. I tried it with a do nothing promise that immediately rejects and still got the error. Does anybody else see this behavior?

Comment: I believe you are correct as well. my code reaches the catch, and i've tried both throwing an error and just promise.reject(). both display this in chrome for me.